# bmon with format option quitafter argument

Tags: command-line, output

I know this might be a stupid question, but as I am new to Ubuntu I don't even know how google it.

I want to show network stats using **bmon** in a special format so I can read it later with another script.

I read through help, and I was able to achieve most of my need using this command:

```
bmon -p 'ens3' -r 3 -o format:fmt='rx=$(attr:rx:bytes) tx=$(attr:tx:bytes)\n'
```

The problem with this command is that it keeps posting stats every x amount of seconds. I want it to only show stats ***once***.

I found in the help that I can use **quitafter**:

```
root@domain:~# bmon -o format:help
format - Formatable Output

  Formatable ASCII output for scripts. Calls a drawing function for
  every item per node and outputs according to the specified format
  string. The format string consists of normal text and placeholders
  in the form of $(placeholder).

  Author: Thomas Graf <tgraf@suug.ch>

  Options:
    fmt=FORMAT     Format string
    stderr         Write to stderr instead of stdout
    quitafter=NUM  Quit bmon after NUM outputs
```

But I can't make it work. I tried a lot of things:

```
bmon -p 'ens3' -r 3 -o format:quitafter=1:fmt='rx=$(attr:rx:bytes) tx=$(attr:tx:bytes)\n'
bmon -p 'ens3' -r 3 -o format:quitafter=1 fmt='rx=$(attr:rx:bytes) tx=$(attr:tx:bytes)\n'
bmon -p 'ens3' -r 3 -o format:fmt='rx=$(attr:rx:bytes) tx=$(attr:tx:bytes)\n' quitafter=1    
bmon -p 'ens3' -r 3 -o format:fmt='rx=$(attr:rx:bytes) tx=$(attr:tx:bytes)\n':quitafter=1
```

None worked.

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This command works on my computer:

```
bmon -p 'wlan0' -r 3 -o format:fmt='rx=$(attr:rx:bytes) tx=$(attr:tx:bytes) ' -o format:quitafter=1
```